# Ajax Alert Firing Twice

Tags: jquery, ajax

The alert keeps firing twice, but not sure why. Any suggestions? `.onoffswitch` is a checkbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.onoffswitch').click(function(){
            var hiddenValueID = $(this).children(':hidden').val();
            if ($(this).children(':checked').length == 0)
            {
                var valueData = '0';
            }
            else
            {
                var valueData = '1';
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: {value: valueData, ID: hiddenValueID} ,
                success: function(html){
                    $("#display").html(html).show();
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

ajax.php...

```
<?php
include('connect.php');

if(isset($_POST['value'])){

    $value=$_POST['value'];
    $id=$_POST['ID'];

    $sql = "UPDATE campaigns SET Status=? WHERE ID=?";
    $q = $db->prepare($sql);
    if($q->execute(array($value,$id))) {
        echo '<script>alert("Campaign Updated");</script>';
        die();
    } else{
        echo '<script>alert("Change Failed - Try Again");</script>';
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: twice the same alert?

Comment: Yes, "Campaign Updated" pops, click ok and another one pops instantly after.

Comment: first, try to test if `success` is being fired twice... put alert before `$("#display").html(html).show();`. if it fired once, then I'm guessing the problem is on this `$("#display").html(html).show();`

Comment: So I put `alert("HI"); $("#display").html(html).show();` Like that? The alert fired twice. Once, followed by `Campaign Updated` alert, then the `Hi` alert again, followed by `Campaign Updated` once again.

Comment: is there any chance that `$('.onoffswitch').click` is firing twice? did you check that?

Comment: instead of `$('.onoffswitch').click(function(){` change it to `$('.onoffswitch').on('change',function(){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of `$('.onoffswitch').click(function(){` change it to `$('.onoffswitch').on('change',function(){` if the element is a checkbox...

Answer (score 1):

Try to use $('.onoffswitch').off('click').on('click',function(event){ in place of $('.onoffswitch').click(function(){

Comment: Still 2 alerts with that one.

Comment: try this also 
$('.onoffswitch').off('click').on('click','.onoffswitch',function(event) {

Answer (score 0):

Is `.onoffswitch` a checkbox? If so, I believe that both the click and the uncheck/check are bound to the click event.

Try using `.mouseup()` instead of `.click()` and see if you have the same problem.

Comment: Yes, it's a checkbox. That sort of solved it. There's only one alert now, but the action is no longer recording in the database.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the relevant HTML. If .onoffswitch is the checkbox, then you don't want to use `if ($(this).children(':checked').length == 0)` but could instead do `if ( $(this).is(':checked') )`

Comment: For some reason that also caused it to no longer update the database.